# How to know what index to create?

Tags: sql-server-2008, indexing, dmv

I queried the "index usage stats" DMV and got the following result

> obj_id:789577851 tab_name:TableX index_id:0 index_name:HEAP user_seeks:0 user_scans:3139598 user_lookups:1237467 user_updates:0

This table does not have any clustered index.

I also looked up the "missing index" DMV but found no entries for "TableX", so that means sql server doesn't think i need to create an index on this table. But there are too many scans and lookups !

I would like to know how should i determine what index is needed to be created to reduce the scans and or lookups ?

Comment: How is the table typically used? If every query that uses it needs, say, 75% of the rows (possibly a lot less, but you hopefully get the idea), then a scan is probably the fastest way to use the table, and no index will help.

Comment: hmm interesting. lemme check.

Answer (score 1):

There is a useful article at [Bart Duncan's SQL Weblog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bartd/archive/2007/07/19/are-you-using-sql-s-missing-index-dmvs.aspx) which shows how this dmv can be joined to give actual create index statements.
It also filters our less important entries in the DMVs.

Hope this is what you were looking for.